# Convert sql query to lambda expression for table with foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have 2 tables. One is a user table that holds userid and userSelection(foreign key to another table) both are primary keys so multiple rows for a user.

The 2nd table holds columns with it's primary id being userSelection.

I want to retrieve all the userSelection rows that a userId has from the 2nd table. I want to use linq lambda expressions too.

I have it working in sql jsut can't convert it for use in c#.

```
Select * From column 
where colID in (
                 select colId from users 
                 where userID = 'someUser')
```

Thanks

Comment: If your table structure is as you say, I would adjust my SQL to this "select * from column c inner join users u on u.colid = c.colid where u.userid = 'someUser'". Subqueries in general should be avoided as they are executed for each row returned by the 'from' clause.

Comment: How would you write that using linq lambda expresssions? I'm not good at converting that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Entity Framework, what you're really looking for is an inner join. it would look something like this:

```
from c in context.Column
join u in context.Users on c.ColId equals u.ColId
where u.UserId = 'SomeUser'
select c;
```

as a lambda that is something like (syntax might be lacking something) (no where clause here, but easily added)

```
context.Column.Join( context.Users, u => u.ColId, c => c.ColId).Select
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. No where are you filtering it by the user

Comment: @zms6445 I corrected the flaw, however I'm assuming that with some basic googling on Entity Framework you can fill in the blanks like a missing "where" function in the fluent api syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code to two parts

```
Select * From column 
where colID in (
                 select colId from users 
                 where userID = 'someUser')
```

First part to get colId list:

```
var colIds = context.users.Where(x=>x.userID == "someUser").Select(x=>x.colId).ToList();
```

Second part to get the result use `Where` and `List.Contains`

```
// IQueryable result
var result = context.column.Where(x=>colIds.Contains(x.colID));
```

You can use it inline, but I recommend it to be two parts.